# Is it possible to keep setgid bit for unzipping files by non root user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zip, unzip, setuid

I have a folder with the following permissions:

```
drwxrws--x+ 13 myuser  www-data      4096 Mar 20 09:57 project-folder
```

In this folder I have an archive `archive.zip` with the following permissions:

```
-rw-rw----+    1 myuser www-data  10260 Mar 20 09:56 archive.zip
```

When I've unzipped archive by calling `unzip archive.zip` I've got following file listing:

```
drwxrwx--x+    3 myuser www-data   4096 May  5  2017 folder-from-archive
```

As we can see, the owner group is `www-data` as same for parent folder `project-folder`, but the `folder-from-archive` does not have **setgid** bit (the 's' part of permissions) and the content of this folder does not owned by group `www-data`:

```
-rw-rw----+ 1 myuser myuser 1083 May  5  2017 LICENSE
-rw-rw----+ 1 myuser myuser 2197 May  5  2017 README.md
-rw-rw----+ 1 myuser myuser  720 May  5  2017 autoload.php
-rw-rw----+ 1 myuser myuser  786 May  5  2017 composer.json
drwxrwx--x+ 3 myuser myuser 4096 May  5  2017 source
```

But when I've tried to unzip this archive as root user the permissions and group owner (as well as the files in the folder) were correct:

```
drwxr-s--x+    3 root www-data   4096 May  5  2017 folder-from-archive
```

Files in folder `folder-from-archive`:

```
-rw-r-----+ 1 root www-data 1083 May  5  2017 LICENSE
-rw-r-----+ 1 root www-data 2197 May  5  2017 README.md
-rw-r-----+ 1 root www-data  720 May  5  2017 autoload.php
-rw-r-----+ 1 root www-data  786 May  5  2017 composer.json
drwxr-s--x+ 3 root www-data 4096 May  5  2017 source
```

As we can see after unzipping by root user the folder inherit sticky bit and set correct group `www-data` for itself and all containing files.

How to get the same behavior for the user `myuser`?

Answer (score 1):

Is the user `root` a member of the `www-data` group? If so, that would explain why the extraction by `root` had the correct group-owner for the extraction.

Similarly, if `myuser` isn't in the `www-data` group, then the files will be extracted as `myuser:myuser`

See `man chmod`:

> ### SETUID AND SETGID BITS
>
> chmod  clears  the  set-group-ID  bit of a regular file **if the file's group ID does not match the user's effective group ID or one of the user's supplementary group IDs**, unless the user has appropriate privileges. Additional restrictions may cause the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits of MODE or RFILE to be ignored.  This behavior depends on the policy and functionality of the underlying chmod system call.  When in  doubt,  check  the  underlying system behavior.

### original notes

I had a user report that files under a setgid path had $user:$user for some files as opposed to the expected $user:$group. I suspected it might be due to archive extraction since the setgid bit was correct up to the the extracted directory, where the group was correct however the setgid missing.

My googling only turned up this single post. Given that I decided to test it, however I'm unable to duplicate the problem using `unzip` also ran a similar test using a tar.gz file and extracting using `tar`:

Create a test archive

```
$ cd ~ && mkdir testdata
$ ls -ld testdata
drwxrwxr-x 12 flakrat flakrat 512 May 16 11:43 testdata

$ cd testdata
$ for n in {1..10}; do mkdir $n; for m in {1..10}; do touch $n/$m; done; done
$ cd ..
$ zip -r -q testdata.zip testdata
```

Create `/project/mygroup`, group workspace with setgid

```
$ cd /project
$ mkdir mygroup && chgrp mygroup mygroup && chmod g+rwxs mygroup
$ ls -ld mygroup
drwxrwsr-x 2 flakrat mygroup 512 May 16 11:46 mygroup
```

Extract the archive

```
$ cd /project/mygroup
$ unzip -q ~/testdata.zip
```

View the results, the group is intact throughout the full extraction tree

```
$ ls -ld testdata
drwxrwsr-x 12 flakrat mygroup 512 May 16 11:43 testdata

$ ls -l testdata
total 0
drwxrwsr-x 2 flakrat mygroup 512 May 16 11:43 1
drwxrwsr-x 2 flakrat mygroup 512 May 16 11:43 10
...

$ ls -l testdata/1/
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 flakrat mygroup 0 May 16 11:43 1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 flakrat mygroup 0 May 16 11:43 10
...
```